# magento2 setup: no CSS

Tags: php, magento2

I have a weird error when trying to develop a magento2 project locally: the backend and frontend work fine, but when I navigate to System -> Web Setup Wizard the page is suddenly missing all styles. I tried the

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

that didn't change anything. It still looks like this (without any console errors):

[image]

Did anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Run Following Commands :-

> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush

After run above commands.your issue will fix.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried that and it didn't help, unfortunately. The wizard is unchanged, the rest of the admin interface looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the total `var` folder and also delete files from the folder `pub/static`. Once this is done, run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't change anything. the backend itself works fine, its just the wizard that seems broken